# Confused and not sure where to start

Tags: html, css

I've been confused for over a month now.

I finished my HTML & CSS courses a month ago, but i haven't had any progress since then. I want to start coding but i have no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write a program that displays "Hello, World!" on the screen?

Comment: How good are you? Can you tell what the error is in `<!DOCTYPE html> <title>?</title> <style>table>tr{background:red}</style> <table><tr><td>Why is this not red?</table>` Or, seriously. What do you want us to do about it, hire you?

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for SO. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a website about something you like.  Then make several CSS files making the website look really different every time.